# Pyqt5 how to parallel QWidget creations

Tags: pyqt5

In my project it is necessary to display a lot of data at once in the mainwindow of my application.
Now I am not quite sure how to implement any parallelization into qt since qt does not allow modification from any other thread than the "main thread" to change ui elements.

Currently I do have only one for loop in my setup function and this creates my `QGroupBox` object on demand. I already tried to take the work load to other cores, but pickle was not able to process my mainwindow. My other experiment was to start a thread which generates all my `QGroupBox` for me and send this object via signal back to the "main thread". Also not successful, since `addWidget` failed because the object was created in another thread with another parent apparently. This confuses me, than the thread has the parent instance of the "main thread" or am I wrong here?

Comment: What evidence do you have that creating the group-boxes will cause any performance issues? Or is this just premature optimisation? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @user20317190 Some important notes: 1. a QThread is not "a thread", it's an interface to it; 2. the parent object of a QThread has nothing to do with what actually happens in the *real* thread; 3. widgets are not thread safe, and cannot be created outside the main thread (or, to be precise, the thread of the QApplication); 4. a process has at least one thread, meaning that each process has its own thread(s); 5. threads belonging to the same process share its memory, different processes don't: they can only communicate through serialization, which isn't possible for abstract objects as widgets.

Comment: @user20317190 This means that, even assuming you find a way to "serialize a widget", you then have to unserialize it, meaning that you will need to create a new widget for the serialized data anyway, making the whole thing pointless. So, not only you can't create widgets in other threads, but doing it in another process would result in the exact opposite of what you're trying to do. The only optimization you can do is to use multiprocessing to *compute* data, but the actual widgets will always be created in the main process and thread.